# JPA Hibernate map more than 2 entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to map my entities in the following manner:

**I have a User and he buys a Car (a specific brand, model and variant).**

To do this, I have created the following classes.

**Car.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CARS")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CAR_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="CAR_MAKER")
    private String maker;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="car")
    private Collection<CarModel> models =new ArrayList<CarModel>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}
```

**CarModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR_MODELS")
public class CarModel {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="MODEL_ID")
    private int modelId;

    @Column(name="MODEL_NAME")
    private String modelName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID")
    private Car car;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="model")
    private Collection<CarVariant> variants = new ArrayList<CarVariant>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}
```

**CarVariant.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR_VARIANT")
public class CarVariant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="VARIANT_ID")
    private int variantId;

    @Column(name="VARIANT_NAME")
    private String variantName;

    @Column(name="FUEL_TYPE")
    private String fuelType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MODEL_ID")
    private CarModel model;

    ..........
      Getters and setters go here
    ..........


}
```

And finally, **User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MASUSER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="USER_REC_ID")
    private int recordId;

    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="USER_EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="USER_PHONE")
    private String phone;


    private Collection<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

}
```

Now, here's my question.

In real life, a user may own many cars, each one with a specific make, model and variant. I would like to implement such a feature with JPA/Hibernate.

I can define a `@ManyToMany` relationship to `User` and `Car`. In that case, if I do `user.getCars().getModels()` or `user.getCars().getModels().get(0).getVariants()` I end up getting everything that's there in the DB.

How do I map `User` and `Car` in such a way that I get the following output?

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| USER_ID     | CAR_ID     | MODEL_ID    | VARIANT_ID  |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 1          | 2           | 3           |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 1          | 2           | 2           |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 3           | 2          | 1           | 1           |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, if you feel I haven't designed my Entity classes right, please feel free to let me know how I can improve.

Thanks

Comment: I t looks like you are trying to have this in table however it has nothing to do with table as far as normalization rules are concerned this data gets divided into different tables but while fetching you can fetch this in this style

Comment: Thank you. Could you please let me know how exactly I can fetch in this style? That's precisely where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch the main object like this

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(User.class);
List<Object> list=criteria.list();
User user=(User)list.get(0);
Car car=user.getCar();
CarModel carModel=car.getCarModel();
CarVarient carVarient=carModel.getCarVarient();
```

In this way you can get each object you are trying to fetch but keep in mind that you are using `FethType.Lazy`And cascadeType.All in everyPojo

Comment: Yes, but I feel this is like doing a @ManyToMany mapping between User and Car in the first place. I want to do a user.getCars() and find out exactly which Car, Model and Variant he owns. Can you help me out on how I can achieve that?

Comment: I will add it to this

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need such a table with all keys from nested relations.

My two cents:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MANUFACTURER")
public class Manufacturer extends AbstractEntity 
{
    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    private Set<CarModel> models = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR_MODEL")
public class CarModel extends AbstractEntity 
{
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANUFACTURER_ID")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "model")
    private Set<CarVariant> variants = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR_VARIANT")
public class CarVariant extends AbstractEntity 
{
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_MODEL_ID")
    private CarModel model;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(name="FUEL_TYPE")
    private String fuelType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="variant")
    private Set<Car> cars = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car extends AbstractEntity 
{
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_VARIANT_ID")
    private CarVariant variant;

    @Column(name = "REGISTRATION_NUMBER")
    private String registrationNumber;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cars")
    private Set<User> users = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User extends AbstractEntity 
{
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String phone;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_CAR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID"))
    private Set<Car> cars = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ......
    Getters and Setters go here
    ......
}
```

1. avoid `Collection`s: use `Set`s where possible (`LinkedHashSet`), or `List`s when you need an `@OrderColumn`
2. give simple names: avoid `MODEL_NAME`, just use `NAME`
3. use a `@MappedSuperclass`, especially if you have a surrogate id for all entities

you can now:

```
Car car = ...;
String manufacturerName = car.getVariant().getModel().getManufacturer().getName();

String jpql = "select c from Car c where c.variant.model.name = 'Golf' and c.variant.fuelType = 'Diesel'";
```